# multi urls in Spring Security prmitAll not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I have a spring boot app and i need to Primit multi urls in security Configration but that not working I did this :

```
@Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/login/**").antMatchers("/register").antMatchers("/home");
    }
```

and this:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/register").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/home").permitAll()
                .and().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().httpBasic();

        http.exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(
                        (request, response, ex) -> {
                            response.sendError(
                                    HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED,
                                    ex.getMessage()
                            );
                        }
                );

        http.addFilterBefore(jwtTokenFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
```

but it's the same, no pages loaded - only login screen appears-
In first code :

[image]

In second one :
[image]

This is my view controller class :

```
@Controller
public class ViewController {
    @Autowired
    IEmployeeRepository employeeRepository;
    @GetMapping("/home")
    public String viewHomePage(){
        return "index";
    }
    @GetMapping("/register")
    public String showRegistrationForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("user", new Employee());

        return "signup_form";
    }

    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String showLoginForm() {
        return "login_form";
    }

    @PostMapping("/process_register")
    public String processRegister(Employee user) {
        BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        String encodedPassword = passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword());
        user.setPassword(encodedPassword);

        employeeRepository.save(user);

        return "register_success";
    }

    @GetMapping("/addCustomer")
    public String addCustomer() {
        return "addcustomer";
    }

    @GetMapping("/addItem")
    public String addItem() {
        return "additem";
    }

}
```

and this is my html :

[image]

signup_ form :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
  <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
  <title>Sign Up</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/webjars/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/webjars/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/webjars/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container text-center">
  <div>
    <h1>User Registration - Sign Up</h1>
  </div>
  <form th:action="@{/process_register}" th:object="${user}"
        method="post" style="max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto;">
    <div class="m-3">
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-4 col-form-label">E-mail: </label>
        <div class="col-8">
          <input type="email" th:field="*{email}" class="form-control" required />
        </div>
      </div>
      <label class="col-4 col-form-label">Serial Number : </label>
      <div class="col-8">
        <input type="email" th:field="*{serialNumber}" class="form-control" required />
      </div>
    </div>

      <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-4 col-form-label">Password: </label>
        <div class="col-8">
          <input type="password" th:field="*{password}" class="form-control"
                 required minlength="4" maxlength="10"/>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-4 col-form-label">First Name: </label>
        <div class="col-8">
          <input type="text" th:field="*{firstName}" class="form-control"
                 required minlength="2" maxlength="20"/>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-4 col-form-label">Last Name: </label>
        <div class="col-8">
          <input type="text" th:field="*{lastName}" class="form-control"
                 required minlength="2" maxlength="20" />
        </div>
      </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label class="col-4 col-form-label">Country: </label>
      <div class="col-8">
        <input type="text" th:field="*{country}" class="form-control"
               required minlength="2" maxlength="20" />
      </div>
    </div>


      <div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign Up</button>
      </div>
  </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The index html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Welcome</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/webjars/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/webjars/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/webjars/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container text-center">
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
    <h3><a th:href="/@{/users}">List of Users</a></h3>
    <h3><a th:href="/@{/register}">Register</a></h3>
    <h3><a th:href="/@{/login}">Login</a></h3>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

and this is Employee model :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee implements UserDetails {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "serial_number")
    private long serialNumber;
    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;


    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "role_id")
    private Role role;
    private String email;
    private String mobileNumber;
    private String country;
    private String password;
    private boolean isDeleted;

    @OneToMany
    private Set<Invoice> invoices;
    @OneToMany
    private Set<InvoiceHistory> invoiceHistories;

    public Employee(){}
    public Employee(long serialNumber, String firstName, String lastName, Role role, String email, String mobileNumber,String country,String password){
        super();
        this.serialNumber = serialNumber;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.role= role;
        this.email = email;
        this.mobileNumber = mobileNumber;
        this.country = country;
        this.password = password;
        this.isDeleted = false;
    }
```

Comment: The second error says it all - error parsing template `signup_form`, nothing to do with spring security. Probably syntax mistake for whatever template engine you are using.

Comment: @Chaosfire so what i should do ?

Comment: Fix `signup_form.html`, obviously... Or edit question to add the contents of the file.

Comment: @Chaosfire i updated it, and notice that index.html have same problem to

Answer (score 0):

The first one you are using ignoring lol.
The second one it's not Spring Security problem. This is Thymeleaf error, check your thymeleaf parsing.

Comment: I update the question

Comment: @renad th:href="/@{/users}" should be th:href="@{/users}" for index.html
and signup_form remove all th:field=*{}.

Comment: It's the same, no changes

Comment: Home also have the same error, where's the problem on it ?

Comment: did you edited register, login also ?

Comment: SignUp page appears, but it's a registration form this will make it in correct, right ? 
home still the same error !